# How do I determine LVM mapping on a physical device?

Tags: linux, lvm

I have a server (SUSE 11.5) that has two disks. There is only one volume group (vg01). How do I determine the physical device on which that vg exists?

Comment: By physical device, what do you mean? A volume group can correspond to multiple disks or partitions. Do you want them all?

Comment: I guess it was poorly-worded, but yes, all of them. Your answer was what I needed - thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think

```
# pvdisplay
```

shows you the physical device(s) corresponding to all your volume groups.

Inter alia, my system shows, for example

```
--- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdc6
  VG Name               olddebian
  PV Size               186.26 GiB / not usable 638.00 KiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              47683
  Free PE               5443
  Allocated PE          42240
  PV UUID               QcpaYU-GuWX-ssIl-U2i9-26Cq-QhQf-fgOyD4
```

This is the only one of my VGs that corresponds to a raw partition. The others are on top of software raid devices.

Comment: @swasheck: In addition to `pvdisplay` showing a lot of information, there is `pvs` with compact output. Similarly there are `vgdisplay` and `vgs` for volume groups and `lvdisplay` and `lvs` for logical volumes.

Comment: @Gilles: yes, pvs is better for this question.

Comment: @Gilles. I'd stumbled across those commands while searching for this answer, but thank you. They will be most helpful for what I need to do, now that I have the initial requirement satisfied.

Comment: Spent half a hour looking for this. Thank you so much for your answer.